# How to address questions that can have multiple answers?

Tags: discussion

Some questions start with 'how' where the user asks how to achieve a certain task. Usually, there are more than one ways to achieve that task. Now when we are writing the answer, which of the following option is more preferred?

1. Writing all the possible ways that I know in one single answer
2. Writing each possible way into a different answer. In this case, I will have multiple answers to a single question.

I couldn't find specific guidelines or SE policies to address this. That's why I asked the question. Also, feel free to suggest other alternatives. The MMSE question that prompted me to ask this meta question can be found [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/whats-the-appropriate-method-to-create-a-supercell-for-quantum-espresso).

Comment: Maybe we can use the one-topic-per answer format for that specific question.

Comment: @NikeDattani in this case the OP didn’t use the one-topic-per-answer tag but I think I'd go with this. I will post an answer detailing one method and then will wait one week to see if someone else adds another, as Tyberius suggested.

Comment: How many methods do you plan on explaining?

Comment: I could add XCrySDen, Phononpy, BURAI, and VESTA. It is also possible with PHON, PWgui, Avogadro, etc.

Comment: I would recommend explaining one of those, like I did [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1222/5) (I know that I also have better examples, but this is the most appropriate one that I found today so far). If you write multiple answers, even with 7 day gaps in between, I worry about the optics of it. In the earlier days of this site, there were some people that looked like they were "gaming" the site and it really looked bad so I discouraged it. I also don't want new users to show up and think they should write 7 answers to 1 question (usually these are not super high quality).

Comment: I encourage users to spend time and energy writing a very high-quality/thorough answer on one topic, rather than writing 7 answers whose answers are less thorough and immaculate in quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have to look if we have written this guideline out elsewhere, but I would generally say for questions with multiple distinct answers, it's best that they are separated into individual posts. This gives voters the ability to express there opinion about each answer individually, which can help give the asker a sense of what the "best" answer is. When all the answers are combined into one post, some of the solutions may be worse than others or just described less accurately, but it's tough for the asker to determine if an upvote reflects confidence in just one part of the post or all the answers it gives.

There are some caveats to this advice. Usually, we prefer having one answer per user on a question. This gives multiple people the chance to answer and avoids the possibility of trying to "game" the reputation system by flooding questions with multiple answers. If you really think a question warrants multiple answers, you should wait some short amount of time (off the top of my head, let's say a week) before adding an additional answer to give time for other users to respond to the original answer and possibly provide answers of their own.

Another exception to splitting might be if you can't provide a detailed description of some/all of the multiple answers. In that case, a single answer that provides a brief survey of possible solutions to the question and points to some more detailed journal articles about each could be useful. This would probably only be necessary if a question isn't receiving any answers and nobody on the site seems to have expertise in any of the individual solutions.